# Estimating confidence of a prediction

Tags: regression, classification, feature-selection, nonlinear-regression

Given a set of features vectors $X=\{\vec{x}_1,..,\vec{x}_n\}$, binary ground truth data $Y=\{y_1,..,y_n\}$ and continuous prediction $\bar{Y} = \{\bar{y}_1,..,\bar{y}_n\}\in [0,1]$, I want to perform some regression analysis to estimate a function $f(\vec{x}_p) \approx e_p$ where $e_p = abs(y_p - \bar{y_p})$.

In practice I want to be able to predict the confidence of a classification based on some external features that do not belong to the classifier itself (that is treated as a black box).

An example could be: I have a classifier that predicts whether a fish is a salmon or a carp. Given a set of features such as weight,size,eye color etc, I want to find a measure that tells me how reliable the classifier is based on those features. E.g. I might find out the classifier is unreliable for fishes of size smaller than 30cm.

I am not an expert in the field and I am looking for the best way to proceed.

Comment: Your tags are incorrect. This has nothing to do with feature selection or non-linear regressions. Classification and regressions won't fit here either, because your question is not necessarily specific to these algorithms rather to evaluation methods in machine learning and some topics in statistics.